# How do I rotate and scale my texture without unwrapping

Tags: texturing, shader-nodes

I wanted to rotate this wood texture and scale it without unwrapping it, is there a way to do this or do I have to unwrap it? (If I made any mistakes with my nodes please feel free to correct them,)

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

plugin these 2 nodes before your image:

[image]

and then you can play around with rotation, location + scale.

Maybe plug it into object or generated, if that fits better for your case.

Comment: If I try this it ends up stretching or warping the texture instead of mapping it to the cabin.

Comment: of course this depends on some things, so please provide your blend file WITH your texture then i can tell you exactly what to do.

Comment: How do I provide a blend file on stack exchange?

Comment: Open https://blend-exchange.com/ and follow instructions

Comment: @Quantian2  UV only works if you've already unwrapped your object.  Try Generated and if that doesn't work then try Object.